# Regexp. eg: <time[HH:mm]>

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regexp to get the the [HH:mm] out of the following, let's say:

Hello, today its <*date[dd/mm/yy]*> and the time is <*time[HH:mm]*>

The things between the [] can be different, it could be dd/mm or mm/yy for the date, HH:mm:ss or mm:ss for the time...

I tried to get something working with wikipedia or regular-expressions.info, but well, I failed, so I need you to help me!:)

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a great site to learn regular expressions.

Comment: `mm:ss for the time`: If hour part is not even provided in original text how can you capture that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\d\d:\d\d$/g
```

See it working at https://regex101.com/r/V4xYfh/1

This basically looks for the HH:MM pattern at the end of the string.

If you need to match anywhere in the string, then this will work

```
/\b\d\d:\d\d\b/g
```

See it at https://regex101.com/r/z3Bskb/1.